# How to configure Mocha with WebStorm

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webstorm

I have issue with running the Mocha tests .

I made configurations for WebStorm, and when I run the Mocha with WebStorm test runner mine tests are working.

But when I run the tests with 'node 'the filename'' from mine terminal I got error of "describe is not defined".

```
const assert = require('assert');

describe('login', function() {
    describe('find_user', function() {
        it('should find the user after login', function() {
            assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
            // should be code for login
        });
    });
});


describe('register', function() {
    describe('register_user', function() {
        it('should find the user after register', function() {
            assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
            // should be code for register
        });
    });
});

describe('contact', function() {
    describe('contact_us', function() {
        it('should find the contact message within the database', function() 
   {
            assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
            // should be code for contact us
        });
    });
});
```

After modifying mine code to this version: I got error "describe is not a function".

```
const assert = require('assert');
const mocha = require('mocha');
const  describe = mocha.describe;
const  it = mocha.it;

describe('login', function() {
    describe('find_user', function() {
        it('should find the user after login', function() {
            assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
            // should be code for login
        });
    });
});


describe('register', function() {
    describe('register_user', function() {
        it('should find the user after register', function() {
            assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
            // should be code for register
        });
    });
});

describe('contact', function() {
    describe('contact_us', function() {
        it('should find the contact message within the database', function() 
 {
            assert.equal([1,2,3].indexOf(4), -1);
            // should be code for contact us
        });
    });
});
```

#### package.json:

```
{
  "name": "couponsystem",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "electron desktop project",
  "main": "js/src/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "electron": "^4.0.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.12",
    "sequelize": "^4.42.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "mocha": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "author": "maks burkov",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Can you explain me what configurations I need in order to run the tests from terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need using mocha test runner to run your tests, just passing test file to node interpreter as you did won't work.

Just add `"test": "mocha"` to the `"scripts": {}` section of your `package.json` and then run `npm test` in your terminal.

See https://mochajs.org/#getting-started